# Unit testing javascript using Jasmine framework

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am very new to Jasmine, infact I just started today and don't have prior knowledge writing JS unit test cases.I am writing unit test using Jasmine for an external javascript file.Unfortunately,I am not quite sure as to how to write a unit test for a function without any parameters.All the examples I have seen so far show a function with atleast one parameter and some value being returned.

The javascript file with the function to be tested.(CreateProvider.js)

```
  var provider = function () {
        var self = this;

 self.formatPhoneNumber = function () {
    if (self.contactNumber().length == 10) {
        self.contactNumber(self.contactNumber().replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1)$2-$3"));
        $("#contactNumber").rules("remove", "max");
        $("#contactNumber").rules("add", { maxlength: 13 });
    }
};

self.formatSSN = function () {
    if (self.SSN().length == 9) {
        self.SSN(self.SSN().replace(/(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3"));
        $("#SSN").rules("remove", "max");
        $("#SSN").rules("add", { maxlength: 11 });
    }
};
 };
```

Now ,I have created another project for jasmine testing.Here I have created another Javascript file.

```
 /// <reference path = ""../../App_Scripts/CreateProvider.js"" />

 describe("providerTests", function () {
   var Provider;

  beforeEach(function () {
      Provider = new provider();
   });

it("should format a phone number", function () {
    //Unit test a function without parameters
});
```

});

Could someone please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Move the logic you want to test into a function that does take parameters.

Comment: So,Is there no way of testing a function which does not take parameters? .. other than doing what you suggested.

Comment: Where is your self.contactNumber and self. SSN() function

Comment: Its within the class

Comment: check the answer posted below you can write some test case in this way

Answer (score 0):

Where your comment is I think you need to add something like this:

```
expect(Provider.SSN()).toBe(/*whatever you expect it to be*/);
```

Comment: Actually If the input is 111111111, I  expect it to be formatted something like this 111-11-1111.Can I write that without actually taking the input.I am going try though

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. To test the SSN() function you would need to supply the input, run the piece of code being tested and then test the output. In the example above you might have a line immediately above it that executes a function (maybe SSN('1111111') ); then you would test the result to check it matches your expectations.

Comment: Actually this is a function which is being called on the blur event of a field.So,the field would already be populated.Hence no need for input parameters.

Comment: OK in that case execute whatever functionality you would expect to be fired by the occurance of the blur event. You need to isolate the function from the DOM event if you want to test it, you need to be able to fire the function and be able to get the output in isolation. Unit tests shouldn't really know about the existence of a DOM (or view) at all.

Comment: So,Are you saying that I should make the function more Generic byremoving SSn and ContactNumber and then test it.

Comment: I think the formatSSN function, for example, should not have the last two lines. These lines don't have anything to do with formatting an SSN (if I've understood the code correctly), rather they are about changing the behaviour of DOM elements. Removing these lines should allow you to unit test this function. 1) Call formatSSN() 2) check the returned value of SSN() and compare it to the expected value (which you would hard-coded into the "toBe" part of the Jasmine sample I gave in the OP).

Answer (score 0):

You can write the test case like this

```
// Success test case

it("should format a phone number", function (done) {
    provide.contactNumber(0801111111);
    provider.formatPhoneNumber();
    expect(Provider.contactNumber()).toBe('(080)111-1111')
    done();
 });
// fail test case since length in not 10
it("length is not equal to 10", function (done) {
    provide.contactNumber(080111111);
    provider.formatPhoneNumber();
    expect(Provider.contactNumber()).toBe(080111111)
    done();
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately,I got an reference error stating 'provider is not defined' and 'Cannot read property 'contactNumber' of undefined'.

Comment: typo error it will Provider, i didn't noticed you have written  var Provider = new provider

Comment: @AbhishekKS: in your `describe` you declare a variable called "Provider" and then in the `beforeEach` you set the value as `new provider()` --- You have the naming conventions for JavaScript completely backwards. "Classes" in JavaScript should be PascalCase e.g. `Provider`, and your variables should be camelCase, e.g. `provider`. Incidently, this is why you are getting an error.

Comment: I had corrected it in my code.Yet,I seem to be getting that error.

Comment: @Greg Burghardt : I can change the naming conventions.But I am getting the error even though I referring to the correct variable.

Comment: how you are requiring the CreateProvide.js file, just at top of the jasmine file write console.log(provider) and see what it is showing in the console

Comment: Its in a different project.So,I added a reference to it in the JS file used in JAsmine.I added this line .. (/// <reference path = "../../App_Scripts/CreateProvider.js" />)

Comment: After the reference path just console for provider and check what is consoling

Comment: the log shows as "Uncaught ReferenceError: provider is not defined".It also shows the status as 404 not found for the CreateProvider Script

Comment: then the reference for the createProvider is not correct just check the path properly

Comment: Its in a separate project. its looks something like this (Project) -> (App_Scripts folder) -> (CreateProvider.js) .. Have I used the correct way to include them in the Jasmine Javascript file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70335/discussion-between-mukesh-agarwal-and-abhishek-ks).